# Automatic memory management when passing an element of a vector in SWIG

Tags: python, c++, garbage-collection, swig

I would like to wrap the constructor  for the object `Foo`, which takes a vector of pointers to `Bar`:

```
    Foo(std::vector<Bar*> const&); //!< Constructor
```

In my interface file I have:

```
%include "std_vector.i" 
%template (vector_bar_p) std::vector<Bar*>;
%include "foo.h"
```

In such a way that from Python I can coreate a Foo like:

```
bar1, bar2 = Bar(), Bar()
foo = Foo([bar1,bar2])
```

The problem is that when `bar1` and `bar2` are garbage collected, the underlying C++ memory is also deleted, and th methods in `foo` result in a segmentation fault. I can solve it with:

```
bar1.thisown = 0
bar2.thisown = 0
```

But I would like a way of setting the `thisown` flag automatically when calling the constrctor of `Foo`, ideally via a typemap in the interface file.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. From [SWIG 3.0 documentation](http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#SWIGPlus_nn38):

> Given the tricky nature of C++ memory management, it is impossible for proxy classes to automatically handle every possible memory management problem. However, proxies do provide a mechanism for manual control that can be used (if necessary) to address some of the more tricky memory management problems.

Also operating with a raw pointer seem suspicious these days. I'd suggest to use either `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Bar>>` or `vector<Bar>` provided with a valid copy-constructor of `Bar`.

Comment: I was thinking more along the lines of something that unsets the thisown flag automatically to anything with that particular type  passed to a function.

Comment: You can make a typemap to set this flag internally.

Comment: I'm having a similar problems as this question address. Alexander is pointing to the possibility of a typemap that sets the thisown flag internally. Question is, how would that be done?